# tar a directory

Tags: linux, command-line, tar

I'm trying to tar my website files that are on my test server to be able to upload them to 'real' server.

```
tar -cf mysite.tar /var/www
```

It creates archive fine... but when I open that archive it has var directory, which contains www directory... **How do I create archive that has /var/www content in its root, not in subfolders** like it's right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are wanting all the files and folders that are in the www folder.  If I am misunderstanding you im sorry.  If that is what you want you could cd into the www directory and run

```
tar -cvf backup.tar *
```

Comment: Keep in mind that globbing like this will not get file's which name begins with a dot.

Comment: How do I get 'dot' files included too?

Comment: Im not good enough with regular expression to figure this one out.  I tried something like 

    tar -cvf backup.tar .??*

but that backs up only the hidden files.

Comment: @mea, do you want to preserve the directory structure **inside** the `/var/www` folder?

Comment: @mea. John T got it right. You're asking for trouble when using `*` with tar. Often it may not matter, but when it does, you probably won't even notice the missing "dot" files (and directories!) until much later. Consider accepting this instead: http://superuser.com/questions/103170/tar-a-directory/103177#103177

Comment: Use "." instead of "*".  That gets the entire content of the current directory

Comment: Also, you can put the cd together with the tar: {cd /var/www; tar -cvf backup.tar .}

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `-C` (capital c) option to make tar change to a directory before it begins it's work. This will effectively remove the directory parents from the archive.

Your other option is to simply run the command from inside the `/var/www` directory itself and avoid this altogether.